# Audio Player : Api response to audio source issue

Tags: flutter, just-audio, flutter-audioplayers

I have a GET API url which returns snippets of audio data.the receiving content-type is audio/mpeg.

How do I continuously call this url to get the data and add as a source in audioPlayer without stopping the player.

Anyone Please suggest me with some code samples.

I am using `just_audio` plugin for the player.

```
String url = 'url';
await _player.setUrl(url,
              headers: {});
_player.playerStateStream.listen((event) {

if (event.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
          print('completed');
          _player.setUrl(url,
              headers: {});
});
```

this is my current player implementation.it will play the continues data from the url.
but each time it completes each snippet , there is a delay in playing next snippet.

these snippets are bytes as in the below format.the content type showing is

> audio/mpeg
> bytes can be concatenated together and we will get a proper music stream.
> Each request will take 300 to 400ms to give the response.
> Iam making the request when each snippet completes playing like in the above implementation.

```
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
```

Please check the attached screenshots for getting the Timing of GET Requests.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add more information to your question about the format of the snippets? Are they truly snippets where the bytes could be concatenated together into a whole properly formatted mp3 file, or instead are these snippets standalone mp3 files that are intended to be played one after the other?

Comment: Also, how exactly does the timing of the GET request map to the actual data you receive? Does making the request a few seconds earlier or later map to different snippets of data? etc.

Comment: Regarding the question of timing, how exactly does the timing of the GET request map to the data you receive? Are you aiming for these snippets to be concatenated seamlessly without any gap? If so, I don't see how that's possible without understanding exactly how to get the next snippet to respond exactly where the first snippet left off.

Comment: @Ryan Heise I need to concatenate these snippets seamlessly. What I am currently doing is , calling the api twice and adding these 2 snippets to array and setting source for the player with the first element in array. after playing the first element ,  Im setting the source with second element.them removes the first and calls next api for next snippet and addinng the response to the array.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't know how exactly the timing of the GET request maps to the data you receive. As I said, I can't see how gapless is possible without understanding the answer to this question. To put this simply, like, when you make a request, how do you know what the next byte of data is going to be, and where it belongs in relation to the bytes you already received on the previous request? Edit: Note S/O is going to tell us soon not to use the comments for discussions. So I'll bow out until that information is clear.

Comment: You still didn't answer my question. I've bowed out, someone else can help you.

Comment: @RyanHeise please check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

i have GET Request which will give blocks of audio( Bytes ) data and I need to stream the continues audio to the player .I'm using CustomAudioSource as follows

```
class MyCustomSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  final List<int> bytes;
  MyCustomSource(this.bytes);

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    start ??= 0;
    end ??= bytes.length;
    return StreamAudioResponse(
      sourceLength: null,
      contentLength: end - start,
      offset: start,
      stream: Stream.value(bytes.sublist(start, end)),
      contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    );
  }
}
```

Steps I followed:

1. I added an array for audio data and initially added 2 responses from the GET API BY calling twice.
2. When the player completes playing each block of audio , I am calling the api to get the next audio block and removing the first element in the array and adding the current response (if (event.processingState == ProcessingState.completed).

   _player.setAudioSource(MyCustomSource(audioData[audioIndex]));

this is how I add new audio blocks to the player.this works fine , but there is a delay in between each block